# Web service receives post object parameters as null

Tags: java, json

1. Service post code receiving the post request from the app.

any help will be appreciated on this one i feel im missing something but i cant figure it out

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addquery", method = RequestMethod.POST,headers  = "Accept=application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String recordEnquiry(@ModelAttribute(value = "enquiry") Enquiry enquiry) 
    {
    //agentDAO.addEnquiry(enquiry);
    log.debug("Received request to add new query");
    String message = "Error posting the ordered details. Please contact admin";

    System.out.println("bsname========"+ enquiry.getBusinessName());
    System.out.println("subject========"+enquiry.getSubject());
    System.out.println("query========"+enquiry.getQuery());
    System.out.println("agent========"+enquiry.getAgent());
    System.out.println("date========"+enquiry.getDate());
    System.out.println("latitude========"+enquiry.getLatitude());
    System.out.println("longitude========"+enquiry.getLongitude());

    agentDAO.addQuery(
            enquiry.getBusinessName(),
            enquiry.getSubject(),
            enquiry.getQuery(),
            enquiry.getAgent(),
            enquiry.getDate(),
            enquiry.getLatitude(),
            enquiry.getLongitude());

    message = "Enquiry Added Successful";

    return message;
}
```

When posting from the app im sending

```
public class HttpPostTask<T> extends AsyncTask<MediaType, Void, String> {
private final HttpJsonPostTaskCaller caller;
private final T objectToPost;
private final String uri;
private final int requestCode;
boolean errorOccured;

public HttpPostTask(HttpJsonPostTaskCaller caller, T objectToBePosted,
                    String uri, int requestCode) {
    super();

    this.caller = caller;
    this.objectToPost = objectToBePosted;
    this.uri = uri;
    this.requestCode = requestCode;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    caller.showLoadingProgressDialog ();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(MediaType... params) {
    try {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        requestHeaders.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        requestHeaders.setAcceptEncoding(ContentCodingType.GZIP);

        HttpEntity<?> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(objectToPost,requestHeaders);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate ();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter ());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter ());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter ());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter ());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter ());
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());

        System.out.println ("objectToPost <=========>"+objectToPost.toString ());
        System.out.println ("objectToPost <=========>"+objectToPost);

        ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,String.class,objectToPost);

        System.out.println ("response <========----=>"+response);
        return response.getBody().toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorOccured = true;
        System.out.println ("Post Task Exception <=========>"+e);
        caller.onAsyncTaskFailed(getClass(), requestCode, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

from app activity

```
protected void saveData(Enquiry enquiry) {
    String uri = getString(R.string.baseURI) + "addquery";


        new HttpPostTask<Enquiry> (Add_EnquiryActivity.this, enquiry,uri, 0).execute ();
    System.out.println("bsname========"+ enquiry.getBusinessName());
    System.out.println("subject========"+enquiry.getSubject());
    System.out.println("query========"+enquiry.getQuery());
    System.out.println("agent========"+enquiry.getAgent());
    System.out.println("date========"+enquiry.getDate());
    System.out.println("latitude========"+enquiry.getLatitude());
    System.out.println("longitude========"+enquiry.getLongitude());


}
```

Logs from the app

```
I/System.out: bsname========brisk sln
I/System.out: subject========test
I/System.out: query========test
I/System.out: agent========8
I/System.out: date========07-12-2016
I/System.out: latitude========-1.2979896
I/System.out: longitude========36.7651589
I/System.out: objectToPost <=========>com.bsl.salesapp.utils.Enquiry@749a070
```

And from web service

```
 bsname========null
 subject========null
 query========null
 agent========null
 date========null
 latitude========null
 longitude========null
```

What might be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Check what objectToPost is being set to. Ensure that this isn't null - I don't see it defined in your code above.

Comment: Thanks. I'd suggest looking at what it's set to in the doInBackground method - e.g. using a debugger in an IDE.

Comment: how do you suggest i do that

Comment: Google is your friend on that - there's plenty of content out there showing how to do this.

Comment: Thanks i figured it out,The issue was with the object class